# Get or set ggplot area width and height

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a dynamically sized plot in Shiny.

```
output$myplotui <- 
renderUI({
    my_width_pixels = ...
    my_height_pixels = ...

    div(style = "position:relative",
     renderPlot({
        ggplot() + ...
    }, width=my_width_pixels, height=my_height_pixels, hover=hoverOpts("plot_hover"))
})
```

The code sets the width and height of the whole plot. How can I set the *plot area* dimensions instead while keeping the hover functionality?

I tried to use

```
grid.draw(set_panel_size(ggplot() + ...))
```

with function `set_panel_size` from this package https://github.com/baptiste/egg/blob/master/R/set_panel_size.r, however I get a shiny error on hovering

```
Error in nearPoints: nearPoints: not able to automatically infer `xvar` from coordinfo
```

As a workaround, how could I at least get the plot area dimensions of my ggplot object when I know my final dimensions? This would allow me to get the right dimension by first generating one or more extra invisible plot.